# Multiple accents on Greek letter in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, accents, greek

I'm new to XeLaTeX and having trouble combining a macron and breve over Greek letters. I input `\textgreek{ᾱ̆}`, but the breve is sitting right on top of the macron. How do I raise it up? Or, alternatively, is there way to make this into a pre-defined glyph?

Comment: Did you try `$\breve{\bar{\alpha}}$`?  Or are we setting Greek text rather than maths?

Comment: I'm setting Greek text rather than maths, but that gives exactly the output I'm looking for, except that I can't get the alpha to come out as the rest of my Greek text (in the CM font).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.